# How to get the parent class inside anonymous class in kotlin

Tags: java, android, android-intent, kotlin

I'm having trouble with Intent creation inside anonymous class in kotlin. I want to reproduce the code below in kotlin:

```
ModuleDAO.INSTANCE.refresh(new AnswerListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnswerRetrieved() {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(int error) {
        // doesn't matter
    }
});
```

What I tried, but doesn't work:

```
ModuleDAO.refresh(object : AnswerListener {
    override fun onAnswerRetrieved() {
        val intent = Intent(SplashScreenActivity::act, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    override fun onError(error: Int) {
        // doesn't matter
    }
})
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this if you want to move from one activity to another-:

```
val intent = Intent(this@OneActivity,TwoActivity::class.java);
intent.putExtra("username", userName)
startActivity(intent);
```